# Авторизация на куки

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация

В любом случае (вне зависимости, сохранены ли куки сайта либо же нет) сайт распознает как авторизованного пользователя. В чем здесь ошибка?

BODY:

```
<?php
//Масив с логинами \ паролями
$users = array();
//Сами данные
$user_1 = array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => '123', 'cookie' => 'sadSU2919KFltRR0');
$user_2 = array('username' => '1', 'password' => '1', 'cookie' => 'Is74xdDkpq00o14k');
//Пускаем их в массив с данными
$users[] = $user_1;
$users[] = $user_2;
//Статус авторизации
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_session'])) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['cookie'] == $_COOKIE['user_session']) {
            $user_who = $user;
            $logged_status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $logged_status = false;
}
//Статус ошибки авторизации
$oops = false;
//Проверка на совпадеине Логина и пароля
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['username'] == $_POST['username'] && $user['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
            setcookie('user_session', $user['cookie']);
            $logged_status = true;
            break;
        } else {
            $oops = true;
        }

    }
}
//Функция выхода
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET == 'logout' && $logged_status = true) {
    setcookie('user_session', NULL, time()-86400);
    header ('Location: /index.php');
    exit;
}
//Что видит авторизованный
if ($logged_status = true && $_COOKIE['user_session']) {
?>

<h1> Авторизация пройдена, <?php $user_who['name'] ?> </h1>

<a href="?do=logout">Выйти</a>
<?php

} else {    //Страница авторизации


?>
<h1> Авторизация </h1>
<?php if ($oops) { ?>
<h4 style="color:red">Кобминация не существует!</h4>
<?php } ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"> : Логин <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"> : Пароль <br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Войти">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте ошибки в своем коде и все будет работать.
Ваша строка с ошибкой - это закомментированная строка справа от валидной.

```
<?php

//Масив с логинами \ паролями
$users = array();
//Сами данные
$user_1 = array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => '123', 'cookie' => 'sadSU2919KFltRR0');
$user_2 = array('username' => '1', 'password' => '1', 'cookie' => 'Is74xdDkpq00o14k');
//Пускаем их в массив с данными
$users[] = $user_1;
$users[] = $user_2;
//Статус авторизации
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_session'])) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['cookie'] == $_COOKIE['user_session']) {
            $user_who = $user;
            $logged_status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $logged_status = false;
}
//Статус ошибки авторизации
$oops = false;
//Проверка на совпадеине Логина и пароля
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['username'] == $_POST['username'] && $user['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
            setcookie('user_session', $user['cookie']);
            $logged_status = true;
            break;
        } else {
            $oops = true;
        }

    }
}
//Функция выхода
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'logout' && $logged_status = true) { //if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET == 'logout' && $logged_status = true) {
    setcookie('user_session', NULL, time()-86400);
    header ('Location: /login.php');
    exit;
}
//Что видит авторизованный
if ($logged_status = true && isset($_COOKIE['user_session'])) { //if ($logged_status = true && $_COOKIE['user_session']) {
?>

<h1> Авторизация пройдена, <?php $user_who['username'] ?> </h1> <!--<h1> Авторизация пройдена, <?php $user_who['name'] ?> </h1>-->

<a href="?do=logout">Выйти</a>
<?php

} else {    //Страница авторизации


?>
<h1> Авторизация </h1>
<?php if ($oops) { ?>
<h4 style="color:red">Кобминация не существует!</h4>
<?php } ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"> : Логин <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"> : Пароль <br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Войти">
</form>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное) исправил все ошибки, все работает как часы